# Why would Abraham establish the morning prayer?

Tags: tefilla, korban, abraham

The Talmud proposes that the morning prayer was established by Abraham ([Berakhot.26b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.26b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=he)):

> "תַּנְיָא כְּווֹתֵיהּ דְּרַבִּי יוֹסֵי בְּרַבִּי חֲנִינָא:
> אַבְרָהָם תִּקֵּן תְּפִלַּת שַׁחֲרִית, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר:
> ״וַיַּשְׁכֵּם אַבְרָהָם בַּבֹּקֶר אֶל הַמָּקוֹם אֲשֶׁר עָמַד שָׁם״,
> וְאֵין ״עֲמִידָה״ אֶלָּא תְּפִלָּה"

> Abraham instituted the morning prayer, as it is stated: “And Abraham rose early in the morning to the place where he had stood before the Lord” (Genesis 19:27), and the verb "standing" means nothing other than prayer,

IIRC, Abraham built altars and sacrificed animals. He was immensely rich and could perfectly sacrifice the morning Tamid.

**Why would he establish the morning prayer?**

Comment: He probably held תפילות אבות תקנם

Comment: Tehillim says להגיד בבקר חסדך. If we take that pasuk as declaring an axiom, then it is reasonable for Avraham, who is known for חסד,  to establish an institution of interaction with Hashem based on speech in the morning.